# How to select multiple folders with shinyDirButton in R

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to write a small shiny app where the user can select multiple folders through a button. The number of folders selected varies according to the needs of the user. The selection of one folder works. If I set "`multiple = TRUE`", then also only one folder is selected. Does anyone have an idea how I can select multiple folders with a single button?

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyFiles)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton("preinfolder", "Choose a folder" ,
                 title = "Please select a folder:",
                 buttonType = "default", class = NULL,
                 icon = icon("folder", lib = "font-awesome"), multiple = TRUE),
  textOutput("prein_txt_file")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  volumes = getVolumes()()
observe({  
  shinyDirChoose(input, "preinfolder", roots = volumes, session = session)
  
  if(!is.null(input$preinfolder)){
    # browser()
    preinfolder_selected<-parseDirPath(volumes, input$preinfolder)
    output$prein_txt_file <- renderText(preinfolder_selected)
  }})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I found (a bit convoluted but it works).
You basically pass the selected folder to a updateCheckboxGroupInput function that appends the folder to a list of previously chosen ones

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
   
   titlePanel("Test"),
   
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         shinyDirButton('fld','Choose...','Choose a folder'),
         actionButton("submitbutton", "Add folder", class = "btn btn-primary"),
         checkboxGroupInput('chosenfolders','Chosen folders...')
      ),
      
      mainPanel(
         verbatimTextOutput("selected")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(), getVolumes()())
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'fld', session=session,
                 root=volumes, filetypes=c('txt'))
  
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    inputfolders <- c(input$chosenfolders,
                      parseDirPath(volumes, input$fld))
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, 'chosenfolders', 
                             choices = inputfolders,
                             selected = inputfolders)
    print(list('Input folders' = inputfolders))
  })

  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    if (input$submitbutton>0) { 
      isolate(datasetInput()) 
    } else {
      return("Server is ready for calculation.")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still trying to solve the problem. I want a list of selected folders.
For my previous solution, I can select multiple folders but only from one parent folder.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyFiles)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyDirButton("preinfolder", "Choose a folder" ,
                 title = "Please select a folder:",
                 buttonType = "default", class = NULL,
                 icon = icon("folder", lib = "font-awesome"), multiple = TRUE),
  uiOutput(outputId = "sel_subfolder"),
  textOutput("prein_txt_file")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  volumes = getVolumes()()
  observe({  
    shinyDirChoose(input, "preinfolder", roots = volumes, session = session)
    
    if(!is.null(input$preinfolder)){
      # browser()
      preinfolder_selected<-parseDirPath(volumes, input$preinfolder)
      output$prein_txt_file <- renderText(preinfolder_selected)
    }})
  df <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$preinfolder)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      fol <- parseDirPath(volumes, input$preinfolder)
      return(fol)
    }
  })
  output$sel_subfolder <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(df())) {
      return(NULL)
    } else if(!is.null(df())) {
      return(tags$div(align = "left",
                      class = "multicol",
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "sel_subfolder",
                                         label = "Select subfolder",
                                         choices = unlist(list.files(parseDirPath(volumes, input$preinfolder))))))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am still looking for a solution how to create a list of multiple folders with one input button.